# Battlefield 3 - Havoc vs. Viper

Tags: battlefield-3

As a passionate Helicopter Pilot in BF3 with over 30 hours, I feel that the US Attack Helicopter (Viper), is way more mobile and maneuverable than the RU Helicopter (Havoc).

How does the Havoc compare against the Viper, esp. in terms of mobility, maneuvrability, firepower/damage, armor etc.? What are the trade-offs in choosing one or the other, or is the Havoc considered inferior to the Viper?

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like you're inviting discussion.  Especially as you're assuming something that may not be correct.

Comment: Just rephrase the question to ask how the two helicopters stack up against each other.

Comment: Actually I dont see why my question isnt accuarte, should be closed or rephrased - I asked if the havoc has any advantages over the viper (firepower,armor) or if he is inferior compared to it.

Comment: I don't know why, but I perform better in the Viper. I've seen no numbers of any kind on either chopper. But the Viper does look cooler.

Comment: This fact was true in BF2, I just thought it was just a cary over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is hard to answer definitively, but here's what I know about the Havoc compared to the Viper:

- Prior to the 1.04 patch for BF3, the Mi28 Havoc was significantly worse at manoeuvring than the Viper. This video highlights the differences quite well:
- The 1.04 patch addressed this with the following change:

  > The Mi28 has received upgrades to its climbing and yawing abilities.
- This video of Havoc yaw speed before and after the patch confirms that it was significantly improved:
- After the patch, there is still some debate as to how similar the two helicopters are. For example, some Reddit users ([example 1](http://www.reddit.com/r/battlefield3/comments/rg8wg/the_havoc_is_pretty_much_on_par_with_the_cobra_now/c45qfxd), [example 2](http://www.reddit.com/r/battlefield3/comments/rg21f/anybody_flown_the_havoc_postpatch/c45jwa4)) believe that the Viper is still better, whereas at least one other ([example](http://www.reddit.com/r/battlefield3/comments/rg21f/anybody_flown_the_havoc_postpatch/c4786s7)) believe that the difference is negligible. Personally, I can't tell a difference between the two now, but I haven't spent enough time in the air to say that with certainty.

Comment: I'd like to add, that Havoc is much wider than Viper, what in some cases causes you to hit the objects you did not expect to and makes impossible to do some stunts (i.e. fly through the main building at the B flag in Op. Firestorm). Generally they are pretty balanced, if people occupying them are relatively equally skilled. However, if you are trying to pilot+gun a heli on your own, as I like to do, you have less chances of surviving against two-manned Viper. Though, note, that people (sometimes including me) often switch teams just to get a Viper, so Viper pilots tend to be more experienced.

Answer (score 0):

The Havoc has more mobility and can yaw, pitch and roll better, firepower is the same as the Viper but in the Viper the TV Missile is easier to control.

Comment: Any sources or evidence for that?

Comment: Regarding the TV Missile - you are wrong, all weapons are completely the same. Source - 75 hours of piloting/gunning and no indication of that in any official resources.

Answer (score 0):

Even before all patches, AH-1Z is really better in manouver and speed comparsion, but Havoc's gunner can blow enemy vehicles very fast with primary cannon...